# Should I put an indefinite article in front?

Tags: indefinite-articles

> There are two main approaches to extracting information from less
>   structured or even free text web pages: classification-based approach
>   and sequential labeling-based approach.

It is from my thesis. A revision suggestion from the committee is that I should add an indefinite article before "classification". In other words, change the whole sentence to:

> There are two main approaches to extracting information from less
>   structured or even free text web pages: a classification-based approach
>   and a sequential labeling-based approach.

The revised version would sound a little strange to my ears. Is it correct?

Comment: Absolutely, I prefer the former, too.

Comment: _Approach_ is a countable noun. Although countable nouns can be converted to uncountable, and vice versa, _approach_ in your sentence is countable. Therefore, you shouldn't use the zero article. Use _a_ if you state them descriptively, i.e., if your readers need the description; use _the_ if you merely direct toward them, i.e., if they already know of them, or should know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My understanding is that determiners (an article is a determiner) can be omitted when the noun is

1. a proper noun (Jim is speaking.)
2. a plural noun (Approaches to consider are...)
3. a non-count noun (Dessert is being served.)

So you might try substituting plural nouns as in this example:

> There are two **types of** approaches to extracting information from
>   less structured or even free text web pages: classification-based
>   **approaches** and sequential labeling-based **approaches**.

Otherwise, with singular nouns, I would say your advisors are right. (By the way, advisors are always right, even when they are wrong!)

You could also omit the noun completely, as in this example:

> There are two approaches to extracting information from
>   less structured or even free text web pages: classification-based
>   and sequential labeling-based.

This sidesteps the need for a determiner altogether.